# CheckBoxList - Restrict selection to a specific number

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I am using a `CheckBoxList` to display a group of Business Units. I want to restrict the selection to max 5 items and if the user selects the 6th Item then i should display an alert and Unselect the 6th Item selected.

The control is as below :

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ckBLBusinessUnits" onclick="loader(this.id);" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ckBLBusinessUnits_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

JS function i am using is:

```
function loader(controlID) {
    modal = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
    modal.style.display = "block";

    if (controlID == "ckBLBusinessUnits")
    {
        if (($('#ckBLBusinessUnits :checkbox:checked').length) > 5)
        {
            alert("Max 5 BU's can be selected");
//is it possible to uncheck here? I am unable to find any method to do so.
        }
    }
}
```

C# is below :

```
protected void ckBLBusinessUnits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (selectedValues.Count <= 5)
            {
                //Do something and then disable the loader.
                loadingImage.Style.Add("display", "none");
            }
            else if (selectedValues.Count > 5)
            {
               //is it possible to uncheck here? I am unable to find any method to do so.
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you asked for, but it might work for your case. Instead of unchecking the checkbox, disable the other checkboxes whenever the total selected items is 5, and show your alert.

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<ListItem> SelectedItems = new List<ListItem>();

        foreach (ListItem ItemsSelected in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (ItemsSelected.Selected)
                SelectedItems.Add(ItemsSelected);
        }

        if(SelectedItems.Count() == 5)
        {
            // Display alert

            foreach(ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
            {
                if(!SelectedItems.Contains(item))
                {
                    item.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        } else
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
            {
                item.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
}
```